# HttpWebRequest in C#: First call is slightly slower

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

When I perform a web request using HttpWebRequest in C#, I noticed the first call to an URL/domain takes slightly longer than subsequent ones. Slightly longer in this case means about 100-150 ms longer, i.e. overall time 150-200 ms instead of 50 ms.

I googled this and came across several users reporting such behaviour. However, in all of these cases there was a delay of several seconds and the problem seems to be related to the proxy settings. That is not the case in my situation.

From experimenting with the "Connection keep alive" header I deduced that it has something to do with the opening of an connection. When I use "keep alive", starting from the second request, the delay is normal. When I use "Connection close", all requests suffer from the described delay.

Here's the minimal code I use for reproducing this problem:

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    var url = "https://www.google.de"; 
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.ReadWriteTimeout = 1500;
    req.Timeout = 1500;
    req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    req.Proxy = null;
    req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

    var start = DateTime.Now;
    var resp = req.GetResponse();
    var end = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);

    resp.Dispose();
}
```

This normally produces an output like this:

```
173.0381
57.3195
66.4853
```

One might be tempted to say establishing the connection simply takes that long. So I analyzed the traffic with the analyzation tool Fiddler. I added Console.WriteLine()-calls for the two variables start and end into the code. That gives:

```
Start 07.08.2020 21:27:49.225
End 07.08.2020 21:27:49.430
```

Now I look at what Fiddler reports:

```
ClientConnected:    21:27:49.237
ClientBeginRequest: 21:27:49.335
GotRequestHeaders:  21:27:49.336
ClientDoneRequest:  21:27:49.336
ServerConnected:    21:27:49.274
FiddlerBeginRequest:    21:27:49.337
ServerGotRequest:   21:27:49.337
ServerBeginResponse:    21:27:49.401
GotResponseHeaders: 21:27:49.402
ServerDoneResponse: 21:27:49.430
ClientBeginResponse:    21:27:49.430
ClientDoneResponse: 21:27:49.430
Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.094
```

So despite being connected at 21:27:49.274 the request only starts about 50 ms later at 21:27:49.335.

Things I've tried include the common recommendations that were given on similar issues on stackoverflow and the web:

- Set the proxy explicitly to null to prevent automatic search for system proxy
- In Internet Explorer network settings disable "Automatic Detection of Settings"
- Use another URL. In this example here I use Google so everyone can reproduce this, but I also tested it with an URL of my own web server and a simple PHP script just echoing the time.
- Disabling the certificate check both via request specific req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and the global ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
- Using a non SSL-URL. In this case the difference between the first and subsequent requests is still there, however it seems to be smaller.
- Bypass the DNS lookup by providing the IP address in the HttpWebRequest.Create() call and later changing the Host-Property of the request object
- Changing other ServicePointManager-related settings, i.e. disabling the Nagle algorithm and the "Excpect 100 Continue".
- Use another computer. Use another Internet connection from a different provider. Use a VPN.
- Use different versions of .NET. Normally I compile with Framework 4.8, but previous versions show the same bevaviour. I tried .NET Core also. That has an even worse overall performance and the first request is still consideraby slower than subsequent ones.
- Use WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest

None of this resulted in a significant change of the behaviour, the first call is still slightly slower than all subsequent ones.

The one thing that did actually work was building the HTTPS-request on my own using TcpClient and SslStream. In this case, all requests have the same latency of about 50 ms for Google. For most cases this is probably not the best solution, I would prefer to use an integrated .NET class.

My questions are: Can you reproduce this? Might this be a .NET bug? Any more suggestions what I could try to prevent this?

Comment: Let [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) (including [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)) rest in peace. Use `HttpClient` instead, especially if you want to do requests as fast as possible. With underlyuing `SocketsHttpHandler` (in .NET Core by default) it twice faster than granny `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: And finally `SocketsHttpHandler` supports HTTP/2. `async` and `await` are [`await`ing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) you. ;)

Comment: @aepot Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that too, but it provided even worse overall performance and still has a performance difference between first request and subsequent ones...

Comment: Maybe you're in .NET Framework. Try `HttpClient` with a default HttpClientHandler in .NET Core then. I gained twice faster HTTP there. The difference in performance can be caused by reuse of connection. First request establishes one but further requests are using the existing connection. And note one important thing: `HttpClient` must be instantiated once, not per request.

Comment: And finally, use `Stopwatch` class to measure the performance, not `DateTime`.